# setNativeProps Change Value for Text Component React Native Direct Manipulation

Tags: react-native

I want to directly update the value of a  component due to performance reasons.

```
render(){

<View>

<Text style={styles.welcome} ref={component => this._text = component}>
  Some Text
</Text>

<TouchableHighlight underlayColor='#88D4F5'
              style={styles.button}>
          <View>    
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}
                 onPress={this.useNativePropsToUpdate.bind(this)}>
              Iam the Child
            </Text>
          </View>  
</TouchableHighlight>

</View>
}
```

This is the method I use to update the text component. I dont know if I am setting the right attribute/ how to figure out which attribute to set:

```
  useNativePropsToUpdate(){
    this._text.setNativeProps({text: 'Updated using native props'});
  }
```

Essentially trying to follow the same approach from this example:
https://rnplay.org/plays/pOI9bA

Edit:
When I attempt to explicitly assign the updated value:

```
this._text.props.children = "updated";
```

( I know this this the proper way of doing things in RN ). I get the error "Cannot assign to read only property 'children' of object'#'"

So maybe this is why it cant be updated in RN for some reason ?

Comment: Use a `TextInput` instead and set the value with `this._text.setNativeProps( { text: 'Hi There!' } )`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of attempting to change the content of `<Text>` component. I just replaced with `<TextInput editable={false} defaultValue={this.state.initValue} />` and kept the rest of the code the same. If anyone know how you can change the value of `<Text>` using `setNativeProps` OR other method of direct manipulations. Post the answer and ill review and accept.

Comment: You can't directly manipulate a `<Text>` because it uses an `NSTextStorage` and not a `NSString` property.
Check this out: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Text/RCTText.h#L15

If there was a way to convert a string value to an `NSTextStorage` value, then we could also manipulate the Text field, but to my knowledge we can't.

Answer (score 4):

We can't use `setNativeProps` on the `Text` component, instead, we can ***workaround*** and achieve the same result by using `TextInput` in place of `Text`.

By putting `pointerEvent='none'` on the enclosing `View` we are disabling click and hence we can't edit the `TextInput` (You can also set `editable={false}` in `TextInput` to disbale editing)

> Demo - Timer (Count changes after every 1 second)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TextInput, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';

class Demo extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let count = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      count++;
      if (this.ref) {
        this.ref.setNativeProps({text: count.toString()});
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} pointerEvents={'none'}>
        <TextInput
          ref={ref => (this.ref = ref)}
          defaultValue={'0'}
          // editable={false}
          style={styles.textInput}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 0.7,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  textInput: {
    fontSize: 60,
    width: '50%',
    borderColor: 'grey',
    borderWidth: 1,
    aspectRatio: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    padding: 5,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default Demo;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The text tag doesn't have a `text` prop, so

```
this._text.setNativeProps({ text: 'XXXX' })
```

doesn't work.

But the text tag has a `style` prop, so

```
this._text.setNativeProps({ style: { color: 'red' } })
```

works.

Answer (score -1):

As setNativeProps not solving the purpose to alter the content of `<Text />`, I have used below approach and is working good. Create Simple React Component like below...

```
var Txt = React.createClass({
getInitialState:function(){
    return {text:this.props.children};
},setText:function(txt){
    this.setState({text:txt});
}
,
render:function(){
    return <Text {...this.props}>{this.state.text}</Text>
}
});
```

Comment: Did you mean `var Text` or `return <Txt`?

Comment: I think this is exactly what was trying to be avoided in the question.